# Problema con namespaces y spl_autoload_register

Tags: php, mvc, namespace

No consigo implementar namespace para que funcione junto con la funcion de autocarga de clases spl_autoload_register

La estructura de mi proyecto
queda de la siguiente manera

```
app
|__ controllers
|         |__inicio.php 
|         |__usuarios.php 
|         |__comprobante.php 
|__ helpers
|         |__app.php // carga los constroladores
|         |__controller.php // instancia la clase Vista
|         |__view.php       //Carga las vistas
|__views
|       |__inicio
|       |       |__index.php
|       |__usuarios
|       |       | __index.php
|       |__comprobante        
|       |       |__index.php
.htaccess  //URL amigables para el usuario
index.php //archivo main que se encarga de autocargar las clases
```

En el **index.php** es donde ejecuta la autocarga de clases

```
<?php
use App\Helpers\App;

spl_autoload_register(function($clase){
    require_once  $clase.'.php';
});

$app = new App;
```

El archivo **App.php** el cual

```
<?php

namespace App\Helpers;

use App\Controllers\Inicio;

class App
{
    function __construct()
    {
        $url = $_GET['url'] ?? null;
        $url = rtrim($url, '/');
        $url = explode('/', $url);

        if (empty($url[0])) {
            $archivoController = 'app/controllers/inicio.php';
            require $archivoController;
            $controller = new Inicio();
            $controller->render();
            return false;
        } else {
            $archivoController = 'app/controllers/' . $url[0] . '.php';
        }
        
        if (file_exists($archivoController)) {
            
            require $archivoController;
            $controller = new $url[0];
           $controller->render();

        } else {
            //controllar errores
            echo 'Error al cargar el recurso';
        }
    }
}
```

La parte de este código recibe el parámetro pasado mediante el **$_GET['url']** valida si esta vacío, de ser así carga la vista por defecto en esa no me genera conflicto el namespace ya que como se define su uso en el principio del archivo **App.php** `use App\Controllers\Inicio`

```
if (empty($url[0])) {
            $archivoController = 'app/controllers/inicio.php';
            require $archivoController;
            $controller = new Inicio();
            $controller->render();
            return false;
        } else {
            $archivoController = 'app/controllers/' . $url[0] . '.php';
        }
```

pero el problema es cuando ingreso una vista diferente, para este ejemplo solo utilizo 3 vistas, cuando ingreso **usuarios** o **comprobante** es ahí donde me salta el error.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ya que como el archivo **usuarios.php** y **comprobante** tienen como `namespace App\Controllers`  el cual considero que el problema ya que el archivo **app.php** no puedo declarar `use App\Controllers\Usuarios` o  `use App\Controllers\Comprobante`, bueno de cierta forma si se podria haciendo uso de switch, pero imaginemos que fueran mas de 10 vistas el código sería mucho,en este caso quiero que sea el mínimo posible.

**1** Una solución seria no agregarles el **namespace** a los archivos de los **controllers** con eso si ingreso la variable correspondiente a la vista no me salta el error.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**2** O hacer un switch cosa, al tener muchas vistas seria más complicado mantener el código.
Adjunto los archivos para su descarga https://github.com/memos1/prueba

Answer (score 0):

Encontre la solución a mi me funciono , se que hay más formas que aun desconozco,

lo primero fue declarar una variable en el archivo **app.php** la cual contendra la ruta del namespace `$use = 'App\\Controllers\\'.$url[0]` y concateno directamente la variable ruta y solo me queda vincular la variable a `$controller = new $use`  y funciona perfectamente ya que de no hacerlo  y si coloco directamente la ruta del namespace a la variable `$controller = new 'App\\Controllers\\'.$url[0]`  me genera un error de tipo  **T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING**, colocar los correspondiente namespace a los archivos controller.